# Over what percentage of acceptance of a phrase is looked on as natural use?

Tags: idiomaticity

This may not be qualified as a query.

Over what percentage of acceptance as idiomatic would normally be considered as felicitous?

For example, if 70% of native speakers agree a phrase is idiomatic, would it be regarded as an accepted use in that language? It may well vary, but what are commonly used guidelines if any?

Comment: Nobody every knows what 70% of native speakers think about anything. There are no such surveys. Have you ever heard of one? It would be prohibitively expensive to run one, and which phrases out of billions would you ask about?

Comment: 90% of survey knowledge regarding language opinions comes from undergraduates in low-level intro courses 99% of who are coerced into participating for free. Those subjects probably constitute under .01% of the "population" in the technical sense. So all we need to do is force more people to take intro courses.

Comment: @jlawler Hi. You are right. I was talking about assumption from a limited size survey. I should have phrased how we could 'assume' the usage is widely, or commonly, accepted. Well, maybe showing the acceptance figure in the survey is the only way. And leave it to the readers to decide.

Comment: @user6726: But these days, for major languages we have MTurk, which allows us to get a much more representative sample. It's still biased against non-Internet users (so you'd likely get fewer samples from elderly) but def. better than coercing LING101 students.

Comment: Don't forget that the real language is spoken, not written. Not even tweeted. Any source relying on letters instead of sounds is not dealing with (or showing anything about real language (though it's usually very interesting, for a relatively short time).

Answer (score -1):

I don’t know what is seen as a gold standard in something like contemporary psycholinguistic statistical research on language processing, but I have heard or read Geoffrey Pullum say that one of the advantages of model-theoretic syntax (MTS) is that it does not require a strict division between grammatically correct vs. incorrect, but can accommodate a range of felicitous valuations, a “fuzzy logic” of syntax, if you will.

This is an excellent paper explaining model-theoretic syntax: https://lingbuzz.net/lingbuzz/003842/current.pdf?_s=_vCM-ZZqPHqR4XTo

This paper uses fuzzy logic, in which there is a continuum of values between true or false (0 to 1), for linguistics: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234784106_A_fuzzy_sets_based_linguistic_approach_Theory_and_applications

This might be the video where I heard him talk about his current thoughts on how linguists have been wont to judge *grammaticality*, and how they perhaps *should*: https://youtu.be/-mUbP1-hLDE

I think it’s an extremely important question since it amounts to the truth-extension on syntax itself, and opens questions if a theory is serving a pre-judged truth-condition or vice-versa, a premature assumption is limiting counter-evidence’s ability to serve as a counterpoint to a contrived theoretical assumption (see Pierce, [abductive reasoning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abductive_reasoning)).

Pullum talks constantly about past linguist’s tendency to *prescribe* how language ought to be, and it seems to be a major interest of his. You should read his Cambridge Grammar of the English Language with Rodney Huddleston, or the Student’s Introduction, for a tour of such questions on evaluating the idea of grammaticality to begin with, before attempting a theory of the grammar of a specific language. I think it really might still be an open question in research, but with interesting and promising new directions uncovered.

---

Some more stuff:

- Elicitation is when you directly query native speakers about the acceptability of a sentence. This method may have a kind of humanistic purity making it in some ways the most direct, I feel, but it can also have a lack of reliability when assumed to be definitive - the results lack ‘representativeness’ for the slipperiness of the method, and arbitrary factors like who was being asked. Possibly, an example of the Piraha language has the shortcoming of it maybe being difficult for people to verify on their own, since it is based on a vary particular language that many people don’t know.
- Magnitude estimation allows for more nuanced judgments and can reveal differences in acceptability that binary judgments might miss (Bard et al., 1996). It is simply elicitation on a gradient, like I said about fuzzy logic.

**Forced-Choice**

Forced-choice, like choosing between lens 1 and 2 at the optometrists, interests me greatly because it creates *relative* valuations as opposed to *absolutist* ones. It presents experiment participants with two or more sentences and asks them to choose the most acceptable one. See Sprouse 2007.

These methods still have methodological problems. The desire to overcome blindspots and biases of more subjective, pseudo-systematic methods with the development of seemingly more systematic procedures - across the social sciences, for example especially in psychology, with statistical significance formulae and “validated questionnaires” and experimental designs like double-blind placebo controlled trials, is still meeting problems like the replication crisis, where the systematicity of the research is still not good enough, and all kinds of unrigorous factors are still at play, causing a deceptive illusion of rigor when in fact there is not. Some of those issues, like sentence selection, and how an experimental context itself may change the decisions of a person whose judgment is being recorded, are discussed in Weskott & Fanselow 2011.

**Corpus Analyses**

Corpus-based methods are an approach which can evade the possible influence of a controlled context like an experiment and possibly evade problems with skewed data by being very, very large. They may not be able to ask people about their thoughts on sentences that have not yet been uttered, but they can find patterns in how people really are using language, and even the kinds of reactions it’s getting, in different contexts, for example, "who do you wonder likes ice cream?" is an odd sentence, but maybe it’s actually used because people really do have an expressive need for it. See Bresnan 2007 and Gries 2015 for more trading on this.

**More complex pattern detection on data*

There has even been a recent technique to use machine learning to “learn” a kind of grammaticality and then study the model to infer what kinds of utterances would be less “grammatical”, in that language, Cherniavskii et al. 2022. Linzen 2020 discusses how meaningful interpretations of these experiments even are, though.

- Bard, E. G., Robertson, D., & Sorace, A. (1996). Magnitude estimation of linguistic acceptability. *Language*, 72(1), 32-68.
- Bresnan, J. (2007). Is syntactic knowledge probabilistic? Experiments with the English dative alternation. In S. Featherston & W. Sternefeld (Eds.), *Roots: Linguistics in search of its evidential base* (pp. 75–96). Berlin: Mouton de Gruyter.
- Cherniavskii, D., Kachkovskaia, T., & Laurinavichyute, A. (2022). Acceptability Judgements via Examining the Topology of Attention Maps. *arXiv preprint arXiv:2205.09630*.
- Gries, S. T. (2015). The most under-used statistical method in corpus linguistics: Multi-level (and mixed-effects) models. *Corpus Linguistics and Linguistic Theory*, 11(1), 133-164.
- Linzen, T. (2020). How can we accelerate progress towards human-like linguistic generalization? *arXiv preprint arXiv:2005.00955*.
- Schütze, C. T. (1996). *The empirical base of linguistics: Grammaticality judgments and linguistic methodology*. University of Chicago Press.
- Sprouse, J. (2007). Continuous acceptability, categorical grammaticality, and experimental syntax. *Biolinguistics*, 1, 123–134.
- Sprouse, J., & Almeida, D. (2017). Design sensitivity and statistical power in acceptability judgment experiments. *Glossa: A Journal of General Linguistics*, 2(1).
- Weskott, T., & Fanselow, G. (2011). On the informativity of different measures of linguistic acceptability. *Language*, 87(2), 249-273.

## My own views

I would like to know more about actual gold standard benchmarks that attain a medical quality of research, for example, in asserting characteristics of language use in brain conditions like Broca’s aphasia, William’s Syndrome, Alzheimer’s, schizophrenia, and others.

I suggest using an olog, a type of categorization technique invented by David Spivak, and I might work on it myself.

An olog doesn’t require you to choose a categorization scheme in advance, but can handle and support any further categories that come up and show relationships they do or do not have towards each other. It sounds promising.

It would be interesting to combine the two so we can combine empirical data with a much more developed theory of context - is the study being done for a certain language, a certain age, a certain period of history, an idiolect, a personality, etc.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.06681v1.pdf
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.09630v2.pdf
https://www.jonsprouse.com/papers/Sprouse%202007b.pdf

It is an extremely important topic. It essentially is what allows us to decide if there is such a thing as “language”, by helping us choose what the boundary is for something which is “not language”. In fact, as of writing this, I wonder if it is the central axiom of the entire field, without which no work could be done, but that might come off as over the top to some people.